# Mutt and Gmail with Local Storage for Readmail

Tags: email, gmail, imap, mutt

I've been using Mutt with Gmail (Google Workspaces) and when I save readmail, it saves them on the imap with a label.

I'd like sentmail and readmail to be stored locally. I only want to use Gmail for inbound e-mail (inbox) and drafts to allow access across devices until processed.

Sentmail is working but not readmail. I've been fighting with this on and off for a while, no luck figuring it out.

Config excerpt:

```
set smtp_url = "smtps://user@host:password@smtp.gmail.com:465/"


mailboxes +readmail
mailboxes +sentmail

set folder = "imaps://imap.gmail.com/"
set spoolfile = "+INBOX"
set postponed = "+[Gmail]/Drafts"
set record = "~/Mail/sentmail"
set trash = "+[Gmail]/Trash"

set imap_user = "user@host"
set imap_pass = "password"

set move = ask-no
set mbox_type = Maildir
```

Welcome any other tips for best practices with Gmail config in Mutt as well. Thanks much for the help.